# Why is jQuery Mobile defaulting all my content theme elements to 'c' and ignoring data-theme? (with Backbone)

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have a view template loaded through backbone into a jQuery mobile front end. I've got the jQuery styles to take effect, but it seems to ignore my data-theme attribute and use teh value 'c' regardless.

Here's the template...

```
<h2>Version Info</h2>
<div id="info">
<a id="addVersionInfoEntryButton" href="#/versioninfo">Add manual entry</a>
<div id="addVersionInfoEntryArea">
</div>
<ul id="items" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-theme="f">
    {{#each items}}
    <li>{{dbVersion}} | {{tag}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</div>
```

And I load it here...

```
        listData: function () {
            this.collection.sort();
            this.$el.html(this.template({ items: this.collection.toJSON() }));
            this.$itemsList = this.$('#items');
            this.$addEntryArea = this.$('#addVersionInfoEntryArea');
            this.$addEntryButton = this.$('#addVersionInfoEntryButton');

            if (this.$itemsList.hasClass('ui-listview')) {
                this.$itemsList.listview('refresh');
            }
            else {
                this.$el.trigger('create');
            }
        },
```

(The refresh and create calls are necessary to get JQM to reprocess the dynamically loaded content). All is fine except for the swatch applied.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

UPDATE:

The data theme applied seems to be applying to the list items but NOT to the data filter, which defaults to 'c'

Comment: are you loading jqm structure.css?

Comment: Yes - all the CSS files are loading fine - It's not a CSS related issue though, as the applied CSS styles are for c rather than f (which is what I've set it to)

Comment: I know, you're using custom CSS themes, created by Themeroller, right? all related CSS files should be loaded.

Comment: I am indeed, and all the CSS files are loaded (they are all pulled together and merged). This isn't a CSS issue though, as the classes rendered in the markup by jQuery Mobile are wrong - If I manually change the markup then it will all look fine.

Comment: can you create jsFiddle for this?

Comment: That would be immensely tricky due to the dependencies of my source code.

Comment: The data theme applied seems to be applying to the list items but NOT to the data filter, which defaults to 'c'